# Visual Studio Code configuratuion for C++ compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

community! I'm trying to compile C++ poject at VS Code that consists of couple .cpp and .h files. How can I configure VS Code to see those files when I CTRL+ALT+N? I get "undefined reference to `pls(double, double)'", but my function pls is defined at .cpp file. I'm missing something...
I use MSYS2 compiler at default settings. C++ 17. Win10.

This is my Task.json:

```
tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp", "${workspaceFolder}\\*.h",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
```

This is what I get in output:

```
[Running] cd "f:\cpp_projects\tst\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "f:\cpp_projects\tst\"main
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\4CFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccetlGLl.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `pls(double, double)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I've done those settings. But still if open main.cpp and just push Run button at top right - i get an error that my fuction is  "undefined reference to". But I can compile project with debug... I don't understand how to make linking between different cpp files so the compiler will know about all cpp files I want to use....

Comment: @drescherjm yeah, the way with "code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ *.cpp -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt" 
works for me, but I don't understand how this solution works. Can you explain what this command in settings is about?

Comment: @drescherjm made edits you asked

Comment: Thank you. I have removed the duplicate close vote because you have the correct `tasks.json`. Someone more experienced with VSCode will have to help.

Comment: @drescherjm ty for link! I understand that the problem lays down at what compiler see when i press Run code in VSC, but how to overcome those linking problems in general? Is there any workflow for big projects in VS Code for C++.

Comment: For big projects its recommended to switch to use CMake for your project and use cmake tools addon: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) or use a Makefile and [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools)